# How center an foreground-image inside an button with dynamic height?

Tags: html, css, image, center

i tried to create a foreground-image on a button.
I already prepared something:

```css
button:hover .remove-me {
  opacity: 1;
}
.remove-me {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<button class="input-image remove-me-container focus" data-btid="3" id="imagepicker_1412162517704">
  <img class="remove-me" src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/64/7909.png" />
  <img draggable="false" height="250px" width="250px" class="img-responsive" src="../../../img/logo.png" />
</button>
```

If possible i would prefer a non-JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `position: relative;` to the `button` then set `top` and `left` of the image to 50%, then use `margin-top` and `margin-left` to move the image back half of its size:

http://jsfiddle.net/g1cbeuho/4/

```css
button:hover .remove-me {
    opacity: 1;

}


button{
        position: relative;
}

.remove-me {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: table-cell;
    position: absolute;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -32px;
    margin-left: -32px;
}
```

```html
<button class="input-image remove-me-container focus" data-btid="3" id="imagepicker_1412162517704">
    <img class="remove-me" src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/64/7909.png" />
    <img draggable="false" height="250px" width="250px" class="img-responsive" src="../../../img/logo.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: Amazing, this one works for me.